Docker compose node js project run failed
I have created a NestJS project and configured it in Dockerfile and able to build and run through command and it's working fine. When I tried to run through docker compose file it failed with nest command not found error, it's working fine in the docker build and run commands.
Docker compose file
version: '3'
services:
  mastermine_api_gateway:
    build:
      dockerfile: nestsample/Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./nestsample:/mastermine_api_gateway
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

Dockerfile
FROM node:alpine3.18

WORKDIR /mastermine_api_gateway

COPY nestsample/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm","run", "start:dev" ]


What's the point of the COPY commands if you're just going to volume mount your working directory anyway? Also, why run npm install twice?

yes just mount node_module folder in docker compose and now its working fine

create .dockerignore file and add node_modules to it

@AllenWong that won't apply to a volume mount
